# How to disable or change color of Tab underline in Android?

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

the default is gray but the color is changed from gray top orange when i press and hold.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the strip line you can create your own tab indicator and then the strip line won't be shown up. This will add the tabs dynamically during runtime (you have to build each tab separately).

I suppose you work with TabHost (please tell me if not). This is an example for one tab creation.

```
// Create tab indicator (background with icon)
LinearLayout tabIndicator = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);

// Create new tab spec from the TabHost
TabSpec newTab = mTabhost.newTabSpec(FINAL_ANY_TAG).setIndicator(tabIndicator);

newTab.setContent(R.id.tabContentXml);

mTabhost.addTab(newTab);
```

While tab_indicator.xml is a layout file for the indicator (at top) which has a background (with a slelector for pressed and unpressed) as you want to build.